# Importing `$defs` section from another schema?

Tags: javascript, json, jsonschema

Is it possible to import the entire `$defs` section from an external schema (using JSON Schema draft 2020)?

For example, let's say I have a set of three schemas like this:

#### "base"

```
{
    "$schema": "https://json-schema.org/draft/2020-12/schema",
    "$id": "https://example.com/schemas/base",
    "$defs": {
        "abc": {
            "type": "string",
            "pattern": "^[abcABC]+$"
        }
    },
    "type": "object",
    "properties": {
        "baseprop1": {
             "title": "base property 1",
             "$ref": "#/$defs/abc"
        },
        "baseprop2": {
             "title": "base property 2",
             "$ref": "#/$defs/abc"
        }
    }
}
```

#### "better"

```
{
    "$schema": "https://json-schema.org/draft/2020-12/schema",
    "$id": "https://example.com/schemas/better",
    "$ref": "https://example.com/schemas/base",
    "type": "object",
    "properties": {
        "betterprop": {
             "title": "an additional, even better property!",
             "$ref": "base#/$defs/abc"
        }
    }
}
```

#### "best"

```
{
    "$schema": "https://json-schema.org/draft/2020-12/schema",
    "$id": "https://example.com/schemas/best",
    "$ref": "https://example.com/schemas/better",
    "type": "object",
    "properties": {
        "bestprop": {
             "title": "the best property!",
             "$ref": "base#/$defs/abc"
        }
    }
}
```

In *base* I've got `$defs/abc` defined. I can reference it in both the other schemas as `base#/$defs/abc`.

But what I'd like to do is somehow import its definition from *base* into *better*, so that in *best* I can reference it as `better#/$defs/abc` instead of `base#/$defs/abc`.

Is there a way to do this?

So far:

- Using `#/$defs/abc` in *best* doesn't work; although I kind of actually expected it to, because I expected the top-level `$ref` to pull everything in to each schema, including the `$defs` object. (Similarily I noticed that `#/$defs/abc` doesn't work from *better*, either, even though I expected it to given the top-level `$ref`).
- I tried this in *better*:

  ```
  "$defs": {
      "$ref": "base#/$defs"
  }
  ```

  But then AJV (at least) complains that `$ref` is not an object/bool (since it's a string). I hand-wavily tried `"base#/$defs/"` as well but that expectedly didn't work either.
- I also tried this in *better*, again hand-waving:

  ```
  "$defs": {
      "allOf": [ { "$ref": "base#/$defs/" } ]
  }
  ```

  But again AJV complained (since it's an array).

I don't really have any other ideas.

Why isn't the `$defs` object being pulled in by the top-level `$ref` (even though e.g. the `properties` objects are being merged with no issue) and why isn't `$ref` working inside `$defs`? Is any of this possible? If so, how?

Also note that I say "import" but maybe there's some sort of "aliasing" type thing instead? **My ultimate end goal is for all the things in *base* `$defs` to appear as if they're actually in *better*, from the POV of *best*.** -- without explicitly just copy + pasting them from *base* to *better*, of course.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the `$id` keyword to give your definitions a new name to use in references, so you don't have to keep track of whether it's defined in base or better:

```json
{
    "$schema": "https://json-schema.org/draft/2020-12/schema",
    "$id": "https://example.com/schemas/base",
    "$defs": {
        "abc": {
            "$id": "https://example.com/schemas/abc",
            "type": "string",
            "pattern": "^[abcABC]+$"
        }
    },
...
}
```

https://json-schema.org/understanding-json-schema/structuring.html

Comment: Sweet; I got that working, and it's a much better approach, too. Thanks!